# Unable configure ExoPlayer for live radio link

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exoplayer2.x

i am trying to make java class for AudioPlayerService for ExoPlayer but

```
getPackName()
```

is not identified
here tis the code i am trying to use in a fragment to stream online radio

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
final ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
DataSource.Factory dateSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getActivity(), Util.getUserAgent(getActivity(), getPackageName()), bandwidthMeter);
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse("online radio streaming link"), dateSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, new Handler(), Throwable::printStackTrace);
ExoPlayer exoPlayer=ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getActivity(),newDefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory));
exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
```

is please help me in making exoplayer that will work for me

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context. getPackageName requires context. Use `getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName()`

> ExtractorMediaSource(android.net.Uri,
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource.Factory,
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory,
>   android.os.Handler,
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource.EventListener)' is deprecate

You should use https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ExtractorMediaSource.Factory.html

Read the constructor

https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ExtractorMediaSource.html#ExtractorMediaSource-android.net.Uri-com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource.Factory-com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory-android.os.Handler-com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource.EventListener-

Comment: ExtractorMediaSource(android.net.Uri, com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource.Factory, com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory, android.os.Handler, com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource.EventListener)' is deprecated

Comment: just look at the docs deprecated. you need to find an alternative

Comment: edited the post and posted links to the docs. read it and use appropriate alternatives

Comment: DataSource.Factory dateSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), Util.getUserAgent(getActivity(), Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext().getPackageName()), (TransferListener<? super DataSource>) bandwidthMeter);

Comment: pls read  the docs. require non null. where do you call getActivity in which method of fragment?

Comment: **(Uri.parse(url), dateSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, new android.os.Handler(), Throwable::printStackTrace);**

this line goes red underline if i use ExctractorMediaSource.Factory, please help me make constructor for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180417/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-smarto-dev).